# How to use system Ruby instead of rbenv on a per-project basis?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I'm using my work laptop to contribute to a non-work open-source project.  At work we use rbenv to manage Ruby versions, but the open-source project appears to expect gem dependencies to be located in the system Ruby install folder.  So when I try to run certain of the project's commands, I'm running into missing gem errors.

The project is Homebrew, and the command I'm running is `brew style`.  When I run the command in my local, I get the following:

```
Ignoring rainbow-2.2.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine rainbow --version 2.2.2
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rainbow (LoadError)
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/richie.thomas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rubocop-0.50.0/lib/rubocop.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/richie.thomas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rubocop-0.50.0/bin/rubocop:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/richie.thomas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rubocop:22:in `load'
from /Users/richie.thomas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rubocop:22:in `<main>'
```

Running `gem environment` returns the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/richie.thomas/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/richie.thomas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/richie.thomas/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/richie.thomas/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/richie.thomas/.gem/specs
....
```

I've been advised by other contributors that the easiest path forward would be to disable or uninstall rbenv in order to run the command.  I'd really like to avoid uninstalling and reinstalling rbenv every time I want to run this command, but there is nothing in the [rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#command-reference) that mentions this.

Is there any one-time command I can run, or any configuration setting I can change, so that I can do what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-ran `gem environment` and noticed that the following environment variables were defined:

```
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/richie.thomas/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/richie.thomas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
```

The value of `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` is what I expected to be used to run the command, and I noticed the value of `USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY` is what showed up in the error stacktrace.

Since I was unable to figure out how my machine was determining which variable to use, I simply renamed `~/.gem/` to `~/.gem2/` and re-ran the `brew style` command I originally wanted.  This was successful!